# bootstrap static assets with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, assets

In bootstrap.css there is a line

```
  background-image: url("../img/glyphicons-halflings.png");
```

What should I replace this url to make it work with ruby on rails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [appropriate gem](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails) instead of linking twitter bootstrap yourself.

Answer (score 0):

In case you would like to modify your `bootstrap.css` to work with asset-pipeline in Rails , you have to find and replace all references of kind `"../img/glyphicons-halflings.png"` to :

```
url(gliphicons-halflings.png)
```

Make sure , that your `.png` files are in a directory managed by asset-pipeline , like explained in [this Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html).